# Can I change the Shares in a Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, share

I have some Shares in a document library in SharePoint Online site which due to an incorrect Tenant setting made the default for a Share "Edit" rather than "Read".

I now want to correct this error by changing all of the existing Shares from "Edit" to "Read".

How do I do this ?

Comment: Is powershell an option?

Comment: If you know how to do it in PowerShell, then I am all ears.